# Should I click "compatibility mode" to install a program written for W8 on W10

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, compatibility

I downloaded a program which is compatible with Windows 8.1.Currently I run Windows 10.I'd like to install this program.What I would like to ask that if I should do something in order run program at best.

When I made right-click I can see that Windows 10 recognized that the program was written for Windows 8 on Compatibility tab.

But should I click  "run this program in compatibility mode" or the program will be run in compatibility mode because windows 10 managed to recognize correctly already?[image]

Comment: You can but you should be able to run it without doing so, since any program compatible with Windows 8.1 is also compatible with Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

As the window itself says "If this program isn't working correctly on this version of Windows, try running the compatibility troubleshooter"

If you have issues & the compatibility troubleshooter recommends to turn on compatibility mode, then follow its advice.

In other words - ***if it ain't broke, don't fix it.***

Generally, Windows 10 should be fine running anything made for Windows 7 onwards.